# UITableView in edit mode doesn't show checkmarks on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a universal app, that has a UITableView that allows standard editing where the cells indent to the right, there's empty circles for unselected rows and the filled in circle with a checkmark for selected rows. This works fine on iPhone (first photo), but the checkmarks don't appear when run on an iPad (second photo). Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

[image: on iPhone]

[image: on iPad]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check autolayout constraints as well as checkmark image for ipad device.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd double check is your Autolayout constraints. Try making sure there are no missing constraints for the checkmark. Because the resolution on the iPad is obviously different than on iPhone, make sure there aren't any fixed distances where it isn't necessary. One way I use to find out if it's an Autolayout issue is by trying different orientations. Hope it helps.